# I want to fill in multiple tables with one form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've checked a lot of other threads before and I couldn't really find anything specific to my issue, which is the following:

I'm working with ApplicationUsers on my project. Next to that, each user has a profile (which is a different table). I want to fill in the profile while I am "creating" a new ApplicationUser in my backoffice, considering they are connected to one another by the userId. The issue is that this is not quite working. I'm using ViewModels and I've made a specific Viewmodel for ApplicationUsers as well (UserViewModel).

So far, I can make a new ApplicationUser perfectly fine, but once i start to try and create a Profile using the same form as the one I've used for my ApplicationUser things starts to go wrong. I have a few hunches where I'm going wrong (for example only using 1 model in my view (create/edit.cshtml, though i'm pretty sure you can only use 1 model on create in a view?).

## Below is my viewmodel for user (UserViewModel.cs)

As you can see here my UserViewModel has a virtual property Profile which should enable the possibility of creating profiles together with the users? Or maybe I'm just dead wrong here already.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using App.Models;
using App.Models.ViewModels;

namespace App.Models.Identity.ViewModels
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }  
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## The following are my edit functions (UserController.cs)

Keep in mind that everything already pretty much works when I remove any reference to the profile. It's when I start to try and add profile fields (be it here or in the view below) that the problems start to arise.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
            }

            var model = _kletsContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            var profile = _kletsContext.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserId == model.Id);
            if(model == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var viewModel = new UserViewModel
            {
                UserId = model.Id,
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Email = model.Email,
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model, Profile profile)
    {
        UserViewModel viewModel = null;

        try 
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
                throw new Exception("The User model is not valid!");

            var originalModel = _kletsContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == model.UserId);
            var originalProfile = _kletsContext.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserId == model.UserId);

            if(originalModel == null)
                throw new Exception("The existing User: " + model.UserName + " doesn't exists anymore!");

            originalModel.UserName = model.UserName;
            originalModel.Email = model.Email;
            originalProfile.Age = profile.Age;


            _kletsContext.Users.Attach(originalModel);
            _kletsContext.Profiles.Attach(profile);
            _kletsContext.Entry(originalModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _kletsContext.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Modified;

            if (_kletsContext.SaveChanges() == 0)
            {
               throw new Exception("The User model could not be saved!");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes.");

            viewModel = new UserViewModel
            {
                UserId = model.UserId,
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Email = model.Email,

            };    
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

## Below is my Edit.cshtml:

```
@model App.Models.Identity.ViewModels.UserViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User";
    ViewBag.SubTitle = "Nieuwe";
    ViewBag.Description = "Aanmaak van een nieuwe User";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Backoffice/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Aanmaak van een nieuwe User
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="hidden">Aanmaak van een nieuwe User</legend>
                        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class="alert-danger"})
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class= "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class= "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Profile.Age)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Profile.Age, new { @class= "form-control" })
                        </div>
                       @Html.ActionLink("Terug naar het overzicht", "Index", new { }, new { @class= "btn btn-default" })
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </fieldset>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Extra: I'll add my ProfileViewModel if necessary, or my DBContext file (or any model). Just let me know. I've been looking at this for a while, but I'm pretty sure that I'm just misunderstanding something pretty basic?

PS: I end up getting the exceptionError so I know there has to be a general problem where nothing inside of my Try works. See the image below

https://gyazo.com/399e59d7d3cfdab2141726fc49ad6786

Comment: Can you set a break point and see what the exception is actually saying? Also, you check to see if `originalModel` is null, but you don't check `originalProfile`. Are you sure it's not null?

Comment: Like, set a breakpoint on the line in the controller where the current error message is? I've not really used breakpoints so far (using Visual Studio Code also, am a Mac user)

Comment: I've added originalProfile to the if statement (checking if it's not null either). It still goes to the catch, so it's safe to say that it isn't null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use a lean flat viewmodel

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }  
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and in your GET action

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{

   var model = _kletsContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
   var profile = _kletsContext.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserId == model.Id);
   if(model == null)
   {
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }

   var vm = new UserProfileViewModel
   {
       UserId = model.Id,
       UserName = model.UserName,
       Email = model.Email,
       Age = profile.Age
   };
   return View(vm);
}
```

Your razor view will be strongly typed to this view model

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.UserProfileViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <label>UserName</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.UserName)

  <label>Email</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Email)

  <label>Age</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Age)
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.UserId)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

And in your HttpPost action, We will use this view model as the method parameter and  the posted form will be converted to an object of this class by the default model binder.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserProfileViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     var u = _kletsContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == model.UserId);
     var p= _kletsContext.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserId == model.UserId);

     //Set the new values
     u.Email = model.Email;

     if(p!=null)
     {
        p.Age=model.Age;
        _kletsContext.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
     else
     {
        // to do  :Create a new profile record
     }
     _kletsContext.Entry(u).State = EntityState.Modified;

    _kletsContext.SaveChanges();
     // to redirect to some success page
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I've incorporated this somewhat into my own logic. It saves the changes so the edit works! Only issue is that it will still send me to my exception despite doing so, which I find somewhat weird. I'll try to figure this out some more. Thanks a bunch though!